# C# Can´t get value from Registry

Tags: c#, registry, nullreferenceexception

I´m trying to get the R install path over C# but unfortunatly the `Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey(keyName)` method returns null.

This is my code:

```
var keyName = @"SOFTWARE\R-core\R";

using (var key = Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey(keyName))
{
   if (key != null)
   {
      var value = key.GetValue("InstallPath", 0);
      Console.WriteLine(value);
   }
   else
   {
      Console.WriteLine("No key found!");
   }

}
```

I manually checked if the key exists and it does.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use

```
Registry.GetValue (String, String, Object)
```

after that you shoul cast object to your type.
More information you can find on MSDN
[GetValue Description](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/microsoft.win32.registry.getvalue(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: I tried that already...it returns the third parameter (the default value)

Comment: Next step. you can check full path to your key to avoid mistake with "Current_User\Local_Machine"

Comment: What do you mean by that?

Comment: My full path is HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\R-core\R. Thats the path I used in your suggested method.

Comment: Maybe you try to reach "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\R-core\R" instead of  "HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\R-core\R"

Comment: I don´t need "HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\R-core\R"...I need "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\R-core\R"